# Load default data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started building an app using the Ionic Framework. But it basically uses Angular.js so the question should be easy to answer :)

The challenge: I have a list of dummy contacts which I can get from a ContactService. Now I'd like to get the actual contacts of my phone. The problem is, that I have to wait for the app to load before I can access the contacts. So I have to wrap it inside an event listener. This is my code, how can I make it work (the success function gets an array of contacts, I checked that)?

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();

  function onSuccess(contacts) {
    ContactService.add(contacts);
  };

  function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
  };

  var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.multiple = true; 
  var fields = ['displayName', 'name'];
  navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}, false);

angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('ContactService', function() {
  var contacts = [];

  return {
    add: function(result) {
      contacts = result;
    },
    all: function() {
      return contacts;
    },
    get: function(contactId) {
      return contacts[contactId];
    },
    count: function() {
      return contacts.length;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't think it's entirely clear what's going wrong or what is working.  Sounds like you've verified you can access the phone contacts via the navigator.contacts property but it just isn't working on "deviceready" ?  is it undefined or do you get some other error or no error, have you tried using $timeout?

Comment: When the app runs the contacts should be available on the ContactService in my opinion. But the list doesn't show any contacts, ContactService.count() returns zero. navigator.contacts works fine. I've tried some things and it looks like I can't access the ContactService inside my onSuccess function